# How to add model in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am new to django and studying ...

First of all I made an application. Reading django book. I successes till "model" concept.

But when I tried to add a model, I am getting some error. Actually how to connect the model in django.

my urls.py looks like

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from videoapp.views import hello, current_datetime, index, list

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^videoapp/$', index),
    ('^videoapp/time/(\d{1,2})/$', current_datetime),
    ('^videoapp/list/$', list),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Template, Context
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime
import MySQLdb



def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")

def current_datetime(request,offset):
    offset = int(offset)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    names={'current_date': now,'total':10}
    t = get_template('mytemplate.html')
    html = t.render(Context({'current': names}))
    return HttpResponse(html)

def index(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    names={'current_date': now,'total':10}
    t = get_template('index.html')
    html = t.render(Context({'current': names}))
    return HttpResponse(html)

def list(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    names={'current_date': now,'total':10}
    t = get_template('list.html')
    html = t.render(Context({'current': names}))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

settings.py

```
# Django settings for videoapp project.
import os
settings_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(settings_dir))

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'videoapp/templates/'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'videoapp',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'root',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': 'localhost',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '3306',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'v*7)@c@qyyoqg0=pbbllrv$$oip*ke^njgr63o1g9gdzc9@x)c'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    #'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',

    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'videoapp.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'videoapp.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #'django.contrib.auth',
    #'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    #'django.contrib.sessions',
    #'django.contrib.sites',
    #'django.contrib.messages',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'videoapp'
    #'videoapp.users'

)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Now I already connected database and there is a table named "users" in db.

I have to create a model and need to fetch all users in "list" view.

Can any one please advice me with the correct way ? Django book is complicated in this part I think.

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you defined any models in models.py?

Comment: yes I added a model in models.py ... Then how to fetch data in list view ? 

from django.db import models

class Users(models.Model):
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()

Answer (score 2):

**models.py**

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=35, unique=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user
```

**views.py**

```
from app_name.models import Sample
def view_name(request):
    samples = Sample.objects.filter()
return render(request, 'page.html', {'samples': samples})
```

**template.html**

```
{% for sample in samples %}
    {{sample.user}}<br/>{{sample.key}}.....
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply .. :) .. May I need to create a file called models.py and paste the above code ? Then how to fetch data in "list" view ? I am completely noob .. Please help

Comment: if you made the django app with `startapp` then you should have an empty `models.py`

Comment: yea !! really thanks for the reply and one question .. each and every model class need to be added in view right ? LIKE from app_name.models import Sample, List, Add etc

Comment: yes if the app they are using is the same. If not need to add in another line